# Suppress the output from Monitor command

Tags: output-formatting

I am working on keeping track of a calculation using progressindicator and monitor. I want the progress bar inside an user interface therefore I want to suppress the output from the monitor command without getting null statement. A simple example is where I have the output

```
Monitor[Table[Length[FactorInteger[2^n - 1]], {n, 50, 200, 15}], n]
```

and when I get null

```
Monitor[Table[Length[FactorInteger[2^n - 1]], {n, 50, 200, 15}], n;]
```

I am taking the value of n and use inside my progressindicator. I have more elaborate "toy" problem if you want to see why I am trying to do that.

Any ideas how I can suppress the output but still keep track of the calculation.

Thank you

Comment: would a method to activate and deactivate at will the `Monitor` be a solution? I mean to prevent the code to be inside of a `Monitor` at all, when needed

Comment: see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92632/27539) for example

Comment: I read it but I think your question little different than mine. My goal is here I always want to monitor. My goal is to take the n from a package and use inside user interface to update the progressindicator. But when suppress the output I have "Null" appearing under my user interface and if I don't suppress it I see the value of n. Both I don't want it. Also you question is quite interesting. The answer is little to advance for my mathematica knowledge but I will play with it to learn.